# JavaFx: NullPointerException when setting text to label from two different functions

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm changing a Label in an fxml file when the user selects a given Tab. I have each tab set up to a given function for #OnSelectionChanged and I have also set up a variable for that specific Label. I don't understand why the Label is properly changed, but I get an error of

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at elorankings.controller.PRSettingsController.changeToIndivLabel(PRSettingsController.java:137)

Here is some of the work that I have done.

```
@FXML
private Label addPlayersInfo;
@FXML
private Tab addBulkTag;
@FXML
private Tab addIndivTag;



@FXML
private void changeToBulkLabel(){
    addPlayersInfo.setText("Add 1 player per line and to add player ranking, seperate them with comma"
            + "\n\nExample:"
            + "\nPlayers Tag, 1600"
            + "\n\nOR"
            + "\n\nPlayers Tag");

}

@FXML
private void changeToIndivLabel(){
    addPlayersInfo.setText("Add Players Individually by providing a tag name and initial ranking.  If no Initial ranking is provided, then player will have the initial ranking that was set on the previous page.");
}
```

[Tab ID and #OnSelectionChanged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNd5G.png)

[Other Tab ID and #OnSelectionChanged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzo8c.png)

The addPlayersInfo Label is set up in an FXML file as follows

```
<Label fx:id="addPlayersInfo" alignment="TOP_CENTER" layoutX="511.0" layoutY="29.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="375.0" prefWidth="180.0" text="Add Players Individually by providing a tag name and initial ranking.  If no Initial ranking is provided, then player will have the initial ranking that was set on the previous page." wrapText="true">

<font>

   <Font size="16.0" />

</font>
```

Thanks in advance for all of the help!

Comment: Presumably `addPlayersInfo.setText("Add Players ...");` is line 137 in PRSettingsController.java. Can you show the FXML where `addPlayersInfo` is defined?

Comment: yes addPlayersInfo is the label that is set up in my FXML file

<Label fx:id="addPlayersInfo" alignment="TOP_CENTER" layoutX="511.0" layoutY="29.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="375.0" prefWidth="180.0" text="Add Players Individually by providing a tag name and initial ranking.  If no Initial ranking is provided, then player will have the initial ranking that was set on the previous page." wrapText="true">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="16.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>

Comment: I went ahead and edited the initial post to show how its set up in my FXML file. 

I then have it in my java file as 
@FXML
private Label addPlayersInfo;

Comment: So that looks correct. You probably need to [edit] your question with a [MCVE] to get a helpful answer.